# How to merge object with jquery by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I need to be able to concatenate two JavaScript objects like the following:

```
let arr1 = [
              {"0": { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }},
              {"1": { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }}
           ];
let arr2 = [
              {"0": { category: "Sport", data: {code: "abdc4051", name: "ab"} } },
              {"1": { category: "Others", data: {code: "abdc4052", name: "abc"} } }
           ];
```

Does anyone have a script for this or know of a built in way to do this?
I want the date to be added in the data on arr2 with the condition code equal to id

Comment: welcome to SO! What have you tried? Where did you fail?

Comment: can u tell here what u are expecting? What is your expected output?

Comment: Why do your objects have sequential initial properties? `{"0": ...}, {"1": ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object shape makes this harder than it should be. Are you certain you want the sequential properties in each object, or is that an artifact of logging/poor parsing?

You'll need to work around them if you actually need them, in the snippet below using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) in creating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from `arr1`, and using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in the final `map()` call on `arr2` to store the sequential key and then reintroduce it in the return after the merge logic.

```js
const
  arr1 = [{ "0": { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" } }, { "1": { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" } }],
  arr2 = [{ "0": { category: "Sport", data: { code: "abdc4051", name: "ab" } } }, { "1": { category: "Others", data: { code: "abdc4052", name: "abc" } } }],

  // create map of dates: Map(2) { 'abdc4051' => '2017-01-24', 'abdc4052' => '2017-01-22' }
  dateMap = new Map(arr1.map(o => {
    const [{ id, date }] = Object.values(o);
    return [id, date];
  })),
  
  // map over arr2, get date from Map and add it to 'data' if it exists
  result = arr2.map(o => {
    const [[k, _o]] = Object.entries(o);
    const date = dateMap.get(_o.data.code);
    return {
      [k]: {
        ..._o,
        data: { ..._o.data, ...(date ? { date } : {}) }
      }
    };
  });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you don't need the initial sequential keys the merge becomes much less verbose.

```js
const
  arr1 = [{ id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }],
  arr2 = [{ category: "Sport", data: { code: "abdc4051", name: "ab" } }, { category: "Others", data: { code: "abdc4052", name: "abc" } }],

  dateMap = new Map(arr1.map(o => [o.id, o.date])),

  result = arr2.map(o => (
    {
      ...o,
      data: { ...o.data, ...(dateMap.has(o.data.code) ? { date: dateMap.get(o.data.code) } : {}) }
    }
  ));

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```